# GPO to remove "Highlight new programs"?

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

I need to disable the "highlight new programs" feature in Windows start menu via a GPO but can't find such a setting. Does such a thing even exist or is it achievable only through registry modification?

Client machines are Win XP, server is Win 2003

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't believe there is a GPO option to disable this. However this option is set by a registry setting so you could create a startup script to set this registry key, to disable this option.

The registry value you're looking for is:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"Start_NotifyNewApps"=dword:{00000000|00000001}
```

It's a REG_DWORD value and should be set to 0 to disable the highlighting, 1 to enable it.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that when google didn't give any useful answers. Registry hack it is then!

Comment: Of course, you can add the registry value by GPO.