# Disable Start menu new Items highlighting by GPO in Windows 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012, group-policy, windows-registry

I need to disable the new items highlighting (New items are marked with "New") on Windows 2012 R2 (remote desktops).

I tried setting the registry value `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Start_NotifyNewApps` used on Windows XP/Vista/7 by GPP (as specified in [GPO to remove "Highlight new programs"?](https://serverfault.com/questions/106778/gpo-to-remove-highlight-new-programs)), but it doesn't work.

I couldn't find any GPO related to this setting.
There is no more option in task bar properties to disable it.

Is it possible to remove highlighting of new items in Start Menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting DOES work, but it has to be set in `...\Explorer\Advanced\..` instead of `\explorer\`.

It removes the 'new' from the Start Menu Apps view.